# decode(null,null,'true','false') = 'true'?

Tags: oracle, null

Today my database world was shattered.

For my whole lifetime I thought, comparing with a `null` value in Oracle results in the "false-case".

But not so for the `decode` function.

Anybody know, what's the idea behind this?

Answer (score 4):

[DECODE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions057.htm#SQLRF00631)

> In a DECODE function, Oracle considers two nulls to be equivalent. If expr is null, then Oracle returns the result of the first search that is also null.